# Send data ajax @RequestParam always null with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have read many answers about this theme but I don´t resolve my problem.

I have a petition ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: CONTEXT_ROOT+'documentacion/clasificar',
        data: {
                idList: idList,
                idNodoSeleccionado: idNodoSeleccionado
        }
    }).done(function (data) { ...
```

and in my Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value="/documentacion/clasificar")
@ResponseBody
public String clasificarDocumentacion(@RequestParam(required=false,name="idList") List<Long> idList, @RequestParam(required=false,name="idNodoSeleccionado") Long idNodoSeleccionado){ ...
```

But my params always receive null.

Whast´s happen? Please, it isn´t repeat question. I have try do all, but work nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this you didn't defined which type of request it is

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/mno/objectKey", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Book clasificarDocumentacion(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String name) {
// code here
}
```

With Spring 4, if your Controller is annotated with @RestController instead of @Controller, you don't need the @ResponseBody annotation.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
   @RequestMapping(value="/controller", method=GET)
  public Book clasificarDocumentacion(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String name) {
  return "Response!";
  }

}
```

You can find the Javadoc for @RestController [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html)

Comment: Not working. Error HTTP Status 400 - Required List parameter 'idList' is not present. What´s happen?

Comment: but you are sending a data... its method type should be post and use json.stringify to send data